# What bosses are good to farm?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are many different repeatable bosses in D3. Some of them are easier than others (Belial isn't hard to defeat if you know the encounter and dodge his attacks).

So what bosses are probably good for bossruns?

Comment: This mechanic is actually disabled. They wanted to promote wandering and exploring over farming any one area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Farming bosses is pretty useless in D3 - you only get guaranteed rare loot the first time you kill a boss.

Besides that, I think none of the bosses is actually *hard* if you know the mechanics.

Comment: I'd say this is incorrect. In the end, boss runs will be necessary, and will still a net a certain amount of blues at the very least. Boss runs will involves running through an earlier part of the quest, and will therefore involves multiple champion mobs. These should provide the bulk of rare items.

Comment: Farming bosses isn't useless. They still give good drops with The Valor buff.

Answer (score 0):

Farming bosses is a great way to end a game after collecting a full stack of five Nephalem Valor buffs. This is due to the increased magic find and the guarantee that you will get extra loot drops from having active buffs. The group I normally run with will start an act a few quests before the final boss to get the loot from killing champions and boss mobs, then finish the game by beating the act boss. This nets a huge amount of loot and allows a great stopping point for checking the auction house.

Source: [Diablo Wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Nephalem_Valor) and Playing Experience

Comment: But *which* bosses do you run? That is the question here...